# How do i parse these two string inside this function in order to be used inside my positions={} , i need integers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps, google-maps-react

I need to parse my "M" and "N", inside my

```
return (
 <Map
   google={this.props.google}
   zoom={14}
   style={mapStyles}
   initialCenter={{
      lat: 32.71573699,
      lng: -117.16108799
   }}
 >
 {this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, M, N }) => {
    return (
      <Marker
        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
        name={A}
        position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
      />)             
  })}

 {this.props.policeCall.map(({  M, N }) => {
    return (
        <HeatMap
          gradient={gradient}
          opacity={3}
          positions={{lat: parseFloat(M), lng: parseFloat(N)}} // parse this part
          radius={30}
        />)
 })}
 <InfoWindow
   marker={this.state.activeMarker}
   visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
   onClose={this.onClose}
 >
   <div>
     <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
   </div>
 </InfoWindow>
 </Map>
);
```

How can i parse my and `n` ? my `M` and `N` are part of a big array, only calling keys m and n for my heatmap but parse them and use them as a floats for my positions. I am using Redux with react and passing data from a different .js file that has a huge array inside of it

Comment: I find it hard to understand what exactly you are asking. Can you please edit the question and provide more details?

Comment: what is the structure of M and N? Are they numbers? strings of numbers? objects?

Comment: they are structured like this { "M": "32.7054544", "N": "-117.1467137"}

Comment: its inside an array of objects , each object has a to n keys but i only need a n or m